# Trying to call a class from program.cs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, quicksort

I created a class to quicksort an array of ints and now im trying to call that class from the program but i keep getting an error, the class is as follows :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace QuicksortSimpel
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static void Quicksort(IComparable[] elements,int left, int right)
        {

            //Define i and j and pick an pivot to compare other numbers
            int i = left, j = right;
            IComparable pivot = elements[left + (left + right) / 2];

            //Compare numbers and then compare to pivot
            while (i <= j)
            {
                while (elements[i].CompareTo(pivot) < 0)
                {
                    i++;
                }

                while (elements[j].CompareTo(pivot) > 0)
                {
                    j--;
                }

                if (i <= j)
                {
                    // Switch
                    IComparable tmp = elements[i];
                    elements[i] = elements[j];
                    elements[j] = tmp;

                    i++;
                    j--;
                }
            }
            // repeat
            if (left < j)
            {
                Quicksort(elements, left, j);
            }

            if (i < right)
            {
                Quicksort(elements, i, right);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I try calling it like this :

```
numbers = Class1.Quicksort(numbers);
```

The error that i am getting is this :

No overload for method quicksort takes 1 arguments.

Comment: Error message isn't clear? Maybe using `params`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `Class1.Quicksort();` takes three arguments and you are passing 1.  And also it does not return anything so doing `numbers = Class1.Quicksort();` will not work.

You could overload or set optional/default parameters (thanks [Silo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1970765/silo) ).

```
public static void Quicksort(IComparable[] elements,int left = 0, int right = 0)
```

or

```
public static void Quicksort(IComparable[] elements)
{
    QuickSort(elements, 0,0);
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the cause of the error. If you want to be able to pass a single parameter, set default values for the left and right values (or create overloads). For example: `QuickSort(IComparable[] elements, int left = 0, int right = 0)`. Also, I'd highly recommend using an `IEnumerable<T>` instead of an array for more flexibility (your return value would also be the sorted `IEnumerable<T>`).

Comment: Ok so when i pass 3 arguments (the array that needs to be sorted) and two ints i will get another error :

The best overloaded method match for 'QuicksortSimpel.Class1.Quicksort(System.IComparable[], int, int)' has some invalid arguments 

and

cannot convert from 'int[]' to 'System.IComparable[]' 

This also happends when i put (IComparable[] elements,int left = 0 , int right = 0) in the class

Comment: @D3l4n0 That could be happening because the array you are passing in is not an array of `System.IComparable` , are you sure that the objects in the array are that?

Comment: @SiLo I put what you suggested in my answer and also added the overload option.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this complier error because class method QuickStart() is expecting three params meanwhile you are providing it with only one param.

Your class is not static so why you are accessing it with Class name ?? You need to create an object of `Class1` then call sort method on that object. I also noted that you are assigning returned value from this method to some variable but in function definition you don't returning anything ??